# Iterating through a JSONArray in Java in order to load them into variables

Tags: java, android

Context: using an API call using OKHTTP so that I can request some information for simple pieces of information (it will be a URL link, and then multiple pieces of text such as the "Track_Name"). Once this info is received, I'm setting it to a load of variables that can be used later.

However, this is where the problem is coming from, as I have only ever had to deal with JSONObjects, not JSONArrays, and therefore don't know how to iterate through them.

I've seen there are two types of For loops, the enhanced for and the for loop. Can someone please advise how I should be approaching this?

This is what my JSON file roughly looks like:

```
  "response": {
    "results": [
      {
        "Track": "https://exampletrackaddress.com",
        "Track_Name": "Example track name",
        "Created By": "111111111111",
        "Track_Code": "YYYYY",
        "Public": true,
        "_id": "12121212121212121212"
      }
    ],
    "cursor": 0,
    "count": 1,
    "remaining": 0
  }
}
```

I've tried running the integer parse that Android Studio recommends but it obviously doesn't help (bit of a long shot!).

```
private CurrentTrack getCurrentDetails (String jsonData) throws JSONException {

        JSONObject track = new JSONObject(jsonData);
        JSONObject trackArray = track.getJSONObject("response");
        JSONArray trackArrayLowerLevel = trackArray.getJSONArray("results"); 

        CurrentTrack currentTrack = new CurrentTrack();

        // assigning the variables of the current track so we have the details
   currentTrack.setTrackCode(trackArrayLowerLevel.getString(Integer.parseInt("Track_Code")));
        currentTrack.setTrackLink(trackArrayLowerLevel.getString(Integer.parseInt("Track")));
        currentTrack.setTrackName(trackArrayLowerLevel.getString(Integer.parseInt("Track_Name")));
        currentTrack.setPublicTrack(trackArrayLowerLevel.getBoolean(Integer.parseInt("Public")));

        return currentTrack;
    }
```

I'm expecting the result to be an item for each entry that I can use to assign to variables.

ERROR MESSAGE:

```
2019-07-21 19:29:50.944 6593-7239/com.example.hypnostream E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
    Process: com.example.hypnostream, PID: 6593
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Track_Code"
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:650)
        at com.example.hypnostream.ListenScreen.getCurrentDetails(ListenScreen.java:132)
        at com.example.hypnostream.ListenScreen.access$200(ListenScreen.java:29)
        at com.example.hypnostream.ListenScreen$1.onResponse(ListenScreen.java:81)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:138)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Comment: Seem like you Track_Code has value "YYYYY" and then you try parse it with Integer.parseInt method. But "YYYYY" is not a number and exception occurs

Comment: `Integer.parseInt("Track_Code")` this is not an integer so you get an exception. I guess you meant something like `Integer.parseInt(trackArrayLowerLevel.getString("Track_Code")))`. However track code in json is not an integer neither so you will get an exception too.

Comment: Have a look at [Integer::parseInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) docs